# Write a program that takes in a year and determines whether that year is a leap year in Coral

Tags: google-coral

Ex: If the input is 1712, the output is:

> 1712 is a leap year.

Ex: If the input is 1913, the output is:

> 1913 is not a leap year.

```
integer inputYear

inputYear = Get next input

if inputYear / 4 == 0
   Put inputYear to output
   Put " is a leap year." to output
elseif inputYear / 400 == 0
   Put inputYear to output
   Put " is a leap year." to output
elseif inputYear / 100 == 0
   Put inputYear to output
   Put " is a leap year." to output
else
   Put inputYear to output
   Put " is not a leap year." to output
```

I'm not wanting the answer, just help with my code. I can't figure out why the if/elseif statements aren't executing.

Comment: @RichEdwards AFAIK, Coral's integer command removes remainders.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out why the if/elseif statements aren't executing.

It's executing, but take 1712 as an example, 1712/4 != 0, and therefore never passes the condition for the if statement. Matter fact, it doesn't pass any of those above conditions.

What you want is modulo math: %.

FYI, check your algorithm.

Comment: Ugh, I completely forgot about the % operator. Thank you!